# How to face track a 3d model

Tags: animation, 3d, motion, tracking

So say I build a 3d character's head how can I use real face motions   to manipulate the 3d model face details, so for example if I raise an eyebrow it will cause the 3d character to raise an eyebrow.

Comment: Are you planning on writing tooling to transfer coordinates from real world to the model? That's pretty complex. I'd suggest using one of the packages that allows you to do this. All they do is allow direct movement of handles from your real world interface instead of having to manually move each one.

Comment: It wont be easy. You would have to first rig the 3d character's head well. Then you would have to do a full head tracking which is complex. You would have to link up the tracking to the 3d model. It wouldn't be easy. http://www.thepixelfarm.co.uk/pftrack-geometry-tracking/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gcz9ZMTDTwY

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xg2jhmLEBuE

https://vimeo.com/145325445